# Sobrescrever first-child css

Tags: css, html5

Bom dia, estou trabalhando com cards do bootstrap e preciso substituir o border radius do header, porém quando tento modificar pelo css eu não consigo devido ao :first-child que tem na classe do bootstrap, alguem sabe como Sobrescrever essa propriedade?

elemento inspecionado do bootstrap

```
.card-header:first-child {
  border-radius: calc(0.25rem - 1px) calc(0.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}
```

Comment: `!important` sobrescreve

Comment: deu certo, vlw cara!!

Comment: Crítica construtiva: "subscrever" é escrever abaixo. "Sobrescrever" é escrever acima.

Answer (score 1):

resolução do problema:

```
.card-header{
border-radius: 20px !important;
```

}

Comment: É a única solução? Quais pontos devo considerar na minha aplicação antes de eu utilizar *cegamente* o `!important`? O que eu ganho com isso e, principalmente, o que eu perco com isso? Poderei alterar essa propriedade em outro ponto da aplicação para sobrescrever o `!important`?

Comment: Me atendeu no que eu precisava

Comment: De certo que sim; a minha intenção era tentar fazer você questionar algo antes de utilizar como solução. Utilizar o `!important` no CSS é algo extremamente complicado e, provavelmente, em todos os casos, desnecessário. Ele quebra a principal característica do CSS: a hierarquia em cascata. Aconselho a buscar as respostas dos questionamentos acima caso já não as conhece, mas fica a seu critério.